# Is it possible to conditionally add a file/folder to NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

Is it possible to conditionally add a file/folder and installation option to a NSIS installer?
My idea is that *if* the folder *Foo* exists at a given location it should be added to the installer and the option to install *Foo* should be added to the installer as well. But if the folder *Foo* does not exist, the NSIS script should just create the installer but leave *Foo* and the option to select *Foo* out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include a file with [/NONFATAL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.5). If it exists, it will be included by the compiler. In runtime, you can check if installer was able to extract it.

```
File /NONFATAL "file.zip"
${If} ${FileExists}  "$OUTDIR\file.zip"
...
${EndIf}
```

Answer (score 0):

In NSIS 2 `File /NONFATAL /R "c:\foo"` is the best you can do without external tools and you need a little hack to hide the section when there are no files:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section "Main"
SetOutPath $InstDir
# File "C:\myfiles\myapp.exe"
SectionEnd

Section "Install Foo" SID_FOO
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /NONFATAL /r "C:\myfiles\foo\*.*"
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
SectionGetSize ${SID_FOO} $0
StrCmp $0 0 "" +3
SectionSetFlags ${SID_FOO} 0 ; Force all flags off including the checkmark
SectionSetText ${SID_FOO} "" ; Hide the section because its size is 0
FunctionEnd
```

If this is unacceptable you can use `!system` and get a little help from cmd.exe to check if something exists:

```
!tempfile INCEXIST
!system 'if exist "C:\myfiles\foo\*.*" echo !define HAVE_FOO > "${INCEXIST}"'
!include "${INCEXIST}"
!delfile "${INCEXIST}"
!ifdef HAVE_FOO
Section "Install Foo"
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /r "C:\myfiles\foo\*.*"
SectionEnd
!endif
```

In NSIS 3 `!if` supports a /FileExists switch:

```
!if /FileExists "C:\myfiles\foo\*.*"
Section "Install Foo"
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /r "C:\myfiles\foo\*.*"
SectionEnd
!endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Example to replace file what depends on running service and exists or not at targget location

```
    IfFileExists "$SYSDIR\my_file.dll" exist notexist

exist:
ExecWait 'net stop desired_service'

SetOutPath $SYSDIR
SetOverwrite on

File "/oname=$SYSDIR\my_file.dll" "Path to my file\my_file.dll"

ExecWait 'net start desired_service'

notexist:
.....what you want to do if doesn't exists
```